# Flexbox don't display items in a row

Tags: css, flexbox

Fast question. I'm trying to use flex...

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="1">
        <img src="sm1.png" alt="1" title="1" /> short_texttexttext
    </div>
    <div class="2">
        <img src="sm2.png" alt="2" title="2" /> short_texttexttext
    </div>
</div>
```

to achieve effect like on the image...[image]

just center, center but flex 'merge' image and text as one item:

IMG text

IMG text

and I want:

> IMG text | IMG text (centered)

The only option is to add additional divs? No way! Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the CSS that you've used so far?

Comment: @Hunter Turner you did assume good. It was css mistake (wrong class name). But [at]Sebastian Brosch provide a good solution so maybe somebody will make use of this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following solutions:

> **Hint:** class names starting with numbers are not allowed in CSS. So you should rename the classes `1` and `2`. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/3840840

**solution #1 (text next to the image):**

```css
.cont {
  background:yellow;
  padding:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.d1, .d2 {
  background:red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="1" title="1" /> short_texttexttext
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="2" title="2" /> short_texttexttext
  </div>
</div>
```

**solution #2 (text under the images):**

```css
.cont {
  background:yellow;
  padding:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.d1, .d2 {
  background:red;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="1" title="1" /><br/>
    short_texttexttext
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="2" title="2" /><br/>
    short_texttexttext
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: LoL I just discovered that my css had wrong name... paymets not payments... flex is working fine now - just as it should from the beginning. I thought I was doing something wrong. Thank you for providing nice solutions! Both are working fine. Marked as accepted answer.